# How to manage concurrent access in an sql procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have create an sql procedure in my oracle database that I will call later on on my c# code,

the main goal of this procedure is to loop over entries and make some treatment in a condition that every entry should be treated only once.

The body of the procedure looks like that.

```
FOR item IN
       ( SELECT * FROM
             (SELECT tab1.item1,tab1.item2,tab1.item3... 
               FROM tab1
               INNER JOIN tab2 ON ...condition...
               INNER JOIN TAB3 ON ...condition...

               WHERE ....main_condition=true;

               ORDER BY  tab1.item1
              )
          WHERE ROWNUM < in_param
        )
    LOOP

        .
        .
        .
        dbms_lock.sleep(4);
        .
        .
        .
        "set main_condition=false;" 
        commit;

    END LOOP;
```

What can I do in a way that when two user call this procedure at the same time, they get a different set of rows.

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> "a condition that every entry should be treated only once."

That sounds like a queue. The usual way of managing that would be to implement the queue with a SELECT … FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED cursor. There is a very important caveat here: that the *treatment* you refer to in your question include something which affects the initial criteria, say by updating a status value or deleting an identifying record (or whatever - unfortunately, questions which are vague about their specifics can only attract equally vague answers).

So it might lock something like this (obviously indicative code):

```
  cursor c_whatever is
     SELECT tab1.item1,tab1.item2,tab1.item3... 
           FROM tab1
           INNER JOIN tab2 ON ...condition...
           INNER JOIN TAB3 ON ...condition...
           WHERE tab1.main_condition = true     
           FOR UPDATE OF tab1.main_condition SKIP LOCKED ;

   begin
       open c_whatever;

       ….
       update tab1
       set tab1.main_condition = false
       where tab1.item1 = ….

       commit;
```

Pessimistic locking will prevent two sessions grabbing the same row. Updating the columns which feed WHERE clause will prevent the same record being treated more than once.

Comment: Isn't it a very wild guess about OP requirement? He might also chose to delete or insert rows in his proc.  From nowhere i could corelate this question for updating anything

Comment: @xing - yes it's a guess but I flatter myself informed rather than wild. If *"every entry should be treated only once"* then there must be some way of tracking **which entries** have been treated. I agree that might not be an update and could could mean a deletion or (less likely) insertion, but the key thing is the *"treatment"* must affect the criteria used in the driving query. I have tweaked that sentence to make it clearer - by making it more vague :-/

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do in a way that when two user call this procedure at the
>   same time, they get a different set of rows.

You can modify your query and use `ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` to get random rows. Hence you can modify your query as

```
SELECT * FROM
             (SELECT tab1.item1,tab1.item2,tab1.item3... 
               FROM tab1
               INNER JOIN tab2 ON ...condition...
               INNER JOIN TAB3 ON ...condition...

               WHERE ....main_condition=true;

               ORDER BY  DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
```

Comment: That doesn't prevent two users getting the same row, though.

Comment: It would in a way..!! If two users query at the same time possibility to have the same row is very less. Might be less than 1%. Isn't it?

Comment: The chances are lower, but not 0 that two users would not get the same row. Presumably the OP wants to guarantee that no rows will be picked up by more than one user.

Comment: Well in that case the possibility of two users calling the same procedure at the same is also very less and on top of that `dbms_random.value` make the situation bit tighter. Ofcourse this one of the way and i guess there is no definite solution to this

Comment: thank you for your answers.
 But the entries should be treated in given order, 
that should not be in a random way.

Comment: @montherzlatan If they have to be picked in the same order then its not possible to do so. You can inturn make an adjustment in a way that no other procedure should run when one is running.  In other words if things have to be sequential then you need to put dependencies